# What do I do to get vim working again?

Tags: vim, makefile

`make test` from within ../vim/src seems to have disabled vim. Nor can I recompile from source.

What do I do to get vim working again?

**Longer Explanation:**

From terminal on a Mac OSX 10.10.4. I was attempting to [modify](https://superuser.com/questions/235505/compiling-vim-with-xterm-clipboard-support) the configuration of vim with the goal of enabling the ability to copy/paste from my system clipboard and also to [enable](http://www.xorpd.net/blog/vim_python3_install.html) python3 encoding.

The code for vim was compiled from source that I cloned from the git repository.

```
git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git
```

I also set it so my version of vim would run instead of the system vim, by adding the following to my .bashrc file

```
alias vim='/the/path/to/my/version/of/vim'
```

After tweaking my ./configure command I ran it as follows.

```
./configure --with-features=huge --enable-perlinterp=yes --enable-pythoninterp=yes --enable-python3interp --enable-multibyte --enable-gui=auto --with-x 
make
make install
```

from within vim I typed

```
echo get('python3')
```

and was pleased to see a "1" indicating that I now had python3 support.

However, when I asked for the version in the command line

```
vim --version
```

I saw that xterm_clipboard was still not enabled.

I hunted around a bit more and saw the suggestion to `make test`
on the python3 [install page](http://www.xorpd.net/blog/vim_python3_install.html). I did that, still from within the ../vim/src folder, and it ran for a couple of minutes, occasionally with bright red errors. I then tried to open vim, but received the following error message followed by a prompt:

```
vim
-bash: /mypath/../src: is a directory
```

So I did a `git pull` and [recompiled](https://gist.github.com/dcosson/3686437) from source without any error messages. However vim still failed to open, with the same error message.

```
command -v vim
```

yielded the path to vim that I had previously assigned in my .bashrc file.

Comment: What happens after you get that "-bash: /mypath/../src: is a directory" error? You just get the next prompt? What does `ls -l /path/to/your/vim` say? That error looks like the target of your alias (or its target if it is a symlink) changed as is now a directory instead of the executable.

Comment: Have you tried `make clean`before attempting to compile again after `git pull`?

Comment: @joepd `./configure.... && make clean && make` gives the same results

Comment: @EtanReisner I just get a prompt after the error.

`ls -l vim -rwxr-xr-x  1 me  staff  2764912 Oct 26 11:01 vim`

Comment: And what does `command -v vim` output at this point?

Comment: Why don't you simply install MacVim?

Comment: @EtanReisner `command -v vim` yields the path that I specified in the `./bashrc` file. `-bash: /Users/my/folders../vim/src: is a directory`. I added `vim` to the end of this string in the `~/bashrc` file, however, I still get the same error message and the same results for `command -v vim`

Comment: `command -v vim` outputs what? The path to the `vim` executable or the path to the `src` directory? Did you start a new shell session after changing your `.bashrc` file?

Comment: @romainl — Weird... So, `brew update && brew install macvim`, and I can't figure out where in the world macvim is, as `macvim` is not a recognized command. But in the process of hunting, `which vim` now shows `/usr/local/bin/vim` and `vim` now works with the latest and greatest 7.4.900. So apparently `brew update && brew install macvim` fixed whatever was wrong. ... now how to open macvim :)

Comment: @EtanReisner `command -v vim` outputs the path to the src directory where vim is. This is the path that I put in my ~/bashrc file. No, I didn't start a new shell session after changing my .bashrc file

Comment: You need the full path to the binary in an alias not the source directory. And changes to `.bashrc` only affect new shell sessions. `/usr/local/bin/vim` almost certainly *is* macvim from brew.

Comment: Did you run `make install` to install your manually-compiled vim into `/usr/local` at some point? Because if you did you shouldn't need an alias to the source directory at all.

Comment: I think this question probably just wants to be deleted as the sequence of events, ultimate problem and actual solution are not at all clear to me at this time.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer if vim is not working is to start a new shell, especially after updating the .bashrc file. Updates to the .bashrc file are only applied to future bash sessions.

*Lessons learned:*

I should not have done a

```
make test
```

When recompiling from code, use

```
make clean
```

*Caveat*
In the end, it is possible that an attempt to install macvim via brew (failed due to a conflict with macports) is what solved the problem, for it was after this attempt (and in a new session) that I was able to open vim again.

Comment: No, it probably just installed a correct version of vim that you can use instead of your broken alias.

Comment: Hmm. Strange, it appears that macvim didn't install after all. `brew list` didn't list is, so I tried to install again and noticed this warning. `Warning: It appears you have MacPorts or Fink installed.
Software installed with other package managers causes known problems for Homebrew. If a formula fails to build, uninstall MacPorts/Fink and try again.` (I do have macports installed.) So, either it was a simple case of me needing to start a new bash session. (Although the changing of the .bashrc file had been at an earlier session) or trying to install macvim somehow fixed something.

Comment: My original question has been answered: what do I do to get vim working again? Thank you each for your help.

Comment: `.bashrc` changes are *not* instant. They *only* affect new shell sessions. `.bashrc` is a shell startup file.